# Gifting money from Canada to Germany

Tags: gift-tax, germany

I have two nieces in Germany and would like to gift some money to them before I die.
Will they have to pay tax on the money ?
Can I just send them a bank draft in Euros ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to research the Canada side of things on your own or maybe someone else can answer that side.

For the Germany side, there is a gift tax (Schenkungssteuer) which depends on the relationship (Verwandschaftsgrad) of the giver and receiver.

steuerklassen.com has an overview [here](http://www.steuerklassen.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/schenkungssteuer.jpg) which shows the tax class (Steuerklasse) and tax free amount (Freibetrag).

So according to the overview, nieces get 20 000 € tax free amount, anything over 20 000 € within 10 years from the same gift giver will be taxed with tax class 2, which can range from 15% to 43% depending on the gifted amount.

The full article is [here](http://www.steuerklassen.com/erbschaftssteuer/schenkungssteuer/)

It also mentiones a few "tricks" for example if you want to gift 40 000 € to your niece, you could gift 20 000 € directly and 20 000 € to your brother or sister who then gifts it to their daughter - you'll have to trust them to do that, though, because you can't put that in a contract. Bottom line of this: If you want to gift more than 20 000 €, your niece should contact a tax advisor (Steuerberater).

About the bank transfer: Your niece will have to declare any bank transfers over 12 500 € that she receives. Her bank will know how to do that so she should just ask them. It also might be helpful for her to have a letter from you stating that the money came from you and is a gift, just in case the tax office (Finanzamt) doesn't believe that the money isn't from moonlighing (Schwarzarbeit).

Comment: Thank you for all the help.
Niece will just have to pay her share of taxes.

Comment: @CatherineGallaherAllen Glad I was able to help. If you find an answer useful, you can upvote and/or accept it to help future readers find the best answers.